# Printing out Javadocs

Tags: printing, javadoc

Something that I've had a good hard look for and I have not been able to find, is how to efficiently obtain a hard copy of Javadocs? Obviously, one solution is simply to navigate to each page and execute a browser print, but there's got to be a better way! Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DocBook Doclet (dbdoclet)](http://dbdoclet.org/) to create [DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/) XML from your JavaDoc Comments. The DocBook XML can then be transformed to PDF or (Singlepage-)HTML.

You can call the tool from the commandline. Point it to your class files and it will generate the DocBook XML. This works similar to the javadoc command which will generate the JavaDoc HTML. Example:

```
./dbdoclet -sourcepath ~/my-java-program/src/main/java -subpackages org.example
```

The result is a DocBook XML file in a `dbdoclet` subdirectory which can be used to create a PDF or HTML file. This can also be done from the command line; I am using the `docbkx-maven-plugin` for this.

You can do mass conversions with it, but it would require some time to make it work the way you want.

Comment: Does it support mass conversion?

Comment: Had a look.. With the example, we have a winner! +50 :)